Confusion about the Argument Principle
This question seems very stupid(low-quality), but I have been thinking about it for a long time and still can't figure it out.

(Argument principle)
Let $C$ be a positively oriented simple closed contour, $D$ the interior enclosed by $C$. Let $f$ be a function that
(1) has only poles as its singularities in $D$;
(2) analytic and nonzero in $C$,
then $$\int_C \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz=2\pi i(N-P),$$
where $N$ is the number of zeros of $f$ in $D$ and $P$ is the number of poles in $D$.


Example: Let $f(z)=z^3e^{z^2}$ for $z \in \Bbb C$ and let $\Gamma$ be the circle $z=e^{i\theta}$,where $0\leq\theta\leq4 \pi.$ Then $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\Gamma} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz =6.$$

In my lecture notes, it says that $$\int_\Gamma \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz=i(\theta_2-\theta_1),$$
where $\theta_2-\theta_1$ is called the total increment of argument of the curve $\Gamma$. Then, $i(\theta_2-\theta_1)=2\pi i(N-P)$, which implies that $$\boxed{\theta_2-\theta_1=2\pi (N-P)\quad \text{or}\quad \frac{\theta_2-\theta_1}{2\pi}=N-P}$$
If this is true, then in this example, the winding number is $2$, but $N-P$ is $3$, what's wrong here?

not sure what version of the argument principle you learned, but it essentially says that the winding number of a (closed) curve times $N-P$ for a function $f$ is the (normalized) difference in the argument of $f$ when you move on the curve which is the integral above, so here you get $2$ (winding number of the given circle as you go twice on it when $0 \le \theta \le 4\pi$) times $3$ ($F$ has $3$ zeroes and no poles inside) equal $6$ (as computed in the OP) which is correct

@Conrad Thank you for your comment! Updated.

I found where I misunderstood. I'm not going to delete this question in case someone has the same problem as me.
The winding number here is not the winding number of the $\Gamma$ curve, but the winding number corresponding to $f(\Gamma)$, thus it is not $2$! Also, if we use this theorem, we should separate the curve into $[0,2\pi]$ and $[2\pi, 4\pi]$, which is a simple curve in each case.
